# parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 7

Tags: shell

I am trying to call an API using Curl. The request was timing out after 60 secs due to TCP Timeout. I added `"-H "Connection: keep-alive" -H "Keep-Alive: timeout=90, max=100"` to the existing code.

```
curl -s -X POST -u $regressionTestAuthToken -H Content-Type: application/json -H Accept: application/json -H "Connection: keep-alive" -H "Keep-Alive: timeout=90, max=100" $URL -d@"${WORKSPACE}"/tmp.json > "${WORKSPACE}"/out.json
```

After adding the Connection Keep-Alive, I am getting a parse error

```
parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 7
```

Can someone help me to triage this issue?

Comment: Is the Keep-Alive stuff relevant to the parse error? Is the error coming from the server? It sounds like it can't parse the JSON. What is in `tmp.json`, and what server are you connecting to?